# How do I access (large) excel (xlsx) files using dbplyr?

Tags: sql, r, excel, xlsx, dbplyr

The `R` library [dbplyr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dbplyr/vignettes/dbplyr.html) allows access to large data files using excel.

I have excel files that are large enough to be problematic and I would like to selectively pull in contents using SQL using dbplyr.

How do I connect to, and access the Excel xlsx file using the dbplyr interface?

Comment: Try setting up a User or File DNS with ODBC Data Sources (assuming you're on Windows) with the excel docs. I believe you can use `DBI::dbConnect()` to set up a connection to the DNS and then `dbplyr()` to do the rest.

Comment: The limits on tables in Excel tend to be well below practical limits in R object size. The only thing I can think of that (in my mind) would justify going the extra steps of indirection using ODBC to access an excel sheet would be if you challenge both the row limits (1M) and column limits (15K?). Otherwise, I suspect just loading the data into R's memory would be better (unless, of course, you regularly deal with numerous worksheets).

Comment: It is at the upper edge of the row limits, middle of the column limits, and multiple sheets/files.  SQL query would be nice.  ODBC is engineered to be one-off, so it takes manual setup each time.

Comment: Take a look at the [bigmemory](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bigmemory/bigmemory.pdf) and [ff](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ff/ff.pdf) packages. These let you handle files that are stored on disk as if they have been read into memory.